# How to optimize query with PL/SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

I have got query of ~53 strings of code and I need to optimize it. I have got PL/SQL Developer 7.0 tool and how should I use it for optimiztion?

I tried to use Explain Plan, but It tells me nothing. I also added time and timestamp columns, but there is nothing interesting, first is empty and second always with same time.

I tried to use Test Window, but there is procedure, that require variable insertion, and as my query select many rows I can't use it.

So question is how can I optimize sql query using PL/SQL Developer? Where should I look for to get query execution time for each subquery? Maybe there are some guides, but for now I found onlyh documentation, but it wasn't usefull fore me? For my current knowledge it looks impossible to optimize such big query without any instruments.

Query, that require optimization:

```
select count(PRODUCT_NUMBER)
  from 
(select W.SUID,
       I.SUID,
       W.PRODUCT_NUMBER,
       MI.ML_NUMBER,
       I.TITLE_TRANSLIT,
       I.COUNTRIES,
       QTY.REMAINS,
       QTY.ACQ_PRICE_USD,
       QTY.REMAINS * QTY.ACQ_PRICE_USD as TOTAL
  from (select UID_WARE,
               QTY as REMAINS,
               ACQ_PRICE_USD
          from (select UID_WARE,
                       PRODUCT_NUMBER,
                       NVL(sum(QTY_ON_STOCK), 0) - NVL(sum(ADD_IN_QTY), 0) + NVL(sum(ADD_OUT_QTY), 0) as QTY,
                       ACQ_PRICE_USD as ACQ_PRICE_USD
                  from (select SI.UID_WARE,
                               W.PRODUCT_NUMBER,
                               count(distinct STK.SUID) as QTY_ON_STOCK,
                               sum(case
                                     when 1 = 1  then
                                      DECODE('' , SM.UID_SOURCE_LOCATION, SM.QTY, 0)
                                     else 0
                                   end) as ADD_OUT_QTY,
                               sum(case
                                     when 1 = 1  then
                                      DECODE('' , SM.UID_DEST_LOCATION, SM.QTY, 0)
                                     else 0
                                   end) as ADD_IN_QTY,
                               ROUND(ACQ.PRICE_USD, 2) as ACQ_PRICE_USD
                          from STOCK_MOVEMENTS SM
                          join STOCK_ITEMS SI on SM.UID_STOCK_ITEM = SI.SUID
                          left outer join (select PR.UID_STOCK_ITEM,
                                                 DECODE(NVL(CR.RATE, 0), 0, 0, PR.PRICE / CR.RATE) as PRICE_USD
                                            from MV_STOCK_ACQ_PRICES PR,
                                                 CURRENCY_RATES CR
                                           where PR.PRICE_DATE = CR.RATE_DATE
                                                 and PR.UID_CURRENCY = CR.UID_CURRENCY) ACQ on ACQ.UID_STOCK_ITEM = SI.SUID
                          join WARES W on W.SUID = SI.UID_WARE
                          left outer join (select distinct STK.SUID,
                                                           STK.QTY_REMAINS
                                             from STOCK_ITEMS STK
                                            where STK.UID_STOCK_LOCATION != 'MS-STL-SALED' 
                                                  ) STK on STK.SUID = SI.SUID
                         where 1 = 1

                         group by SI.UID_WARE,
                                  W.PRODUCT_NUMBER,
                                  ACQ.PRICE_USD
                        ) T
                 group by T.UID_WARE,
                          T.PRODUCT_NUMBER,
                          ACQ_PRICE_USD)) QTY
  join WARES W on W.SUID = QTY.UID_WARE
  join INVENTORY I on I.SUID = W.UID_ISSUE
  join MAP_INFO MI on MI.SUID = I.SUID
 where REMAINS != 0
       and w.UID_SECTION in ('MS-SEC-BOOKS', 'MS-SEC-MAPS'))
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use a GUI to analyse and optimise a query you are locking yourself in to a much smaller community of potential assistance. If you run explain plan and use DBMS_XPlan.Display to fetch the formatted result then you are working with a standard method understood by tens of thousands of practitioners.

Also, I'm suspicious that you have wrapped the query in an outer query with just count(*). Although this may be to run the query without the hassle of returning all the rows you could well be getting a completely different execution plan, and although there are hints that might help promote the use of the usual plan there is no guarantee that it won't change. So, if this is a convenience for the sake of tuning, take it away.

So my advice:

1. Run the explain plan the regular query-based way and do not rely on tools that "help".
2. Run the actual query you need to tune.
3. Post the execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

For execution time, from [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=703536):

```
SQL> set timing on;
```

In PL/SQL Developer you can run each subquery independently - mark it with your mouse and press <kbd>F8</kbd>. You will see execution time in lower left corner of sql window (below the results).

Optimalization is not an easy task, you have to think by yourself - according to my knowledge, there are no tools to do this for you. Your aproach may depend on many factors - db version, underlying os, table size, indexing, ...

You can read some guides (like [this](http://docs.oracle.com/html/A95912_01/wn32tune.htm), [this](http://hungred.com/useful-information/ways-optimize-sql-queries/) or [this](http://www.dba-oracle.com/art_sql_tune.htm))

**UPDATE**

Depending on your db version, you can try using [CTE](http://www.morganslibrary.org/reference/with.html) or [SQL modelling](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/sqlmodel.htm) - they will improve performance for sure, but require some time to learn.

Instead of `group by`, you can try [analytic functions](http://psoug.org/reference/analytic_functions.html) (e.g. `partition by`, see [this link](http://www.orafaq.com/node/55) for examples).

Comment: I think it's inaccurate with F8. Because subqueries fetching in 500 seconds when I execute it independently, when full query proceed for 80 seconds.

Comment: I can use only project and PL/SQL Developer, I haven't got access to anything else. Ofcource I should do it by myself, but I just want to understand where is the problem in ~7 selects, 6 'group by's and 5 joins. I can't optimize something I didn't know.

Comment: edit your question and post your query, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Done, but I don't think posting query will help.